# ¿ cómo instalar el modulo time de la standar lib de python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

llevo 1 hora intentando instalar el módulo "sleep" para Python, bueno, cada vez que lo hago, me sale el error

```
C:\Windows\Temp>pip install sleep
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sleep (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sleep

C:\Windows\Temp>
```

Ya he intentado reinstalando pip, desinstalando Python 3.6 y 3.8, para luego instalar 3.9 y nada, desinstalé todos mis módulos, y nada funciona. Alguien me puede ayudar?
Mi versión de Python es 3.9.0 y la version de pip es 20.2.4

Answer (score 2):

Solo necesitas:

```
from time import sleep
```

time es parte de la librería standar de Python por lo que no requiere instalación alguna.

Comment: Ahhh gracias, pensaba que se tenía que instalar, soy medio-novato en Python

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta puedes marcarla como válida @MatteoCuneo.